# Переклад слова "Rickrolling"

Tags: переклад, from-english

Доброго дня!
В Інтернеті, особливо на сайтах англомовних спільнот, досить часто можна зустріти слово [Rickrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rickrolling) (комбінація слів "Rick" та "roll") , що означає жарт, коли людина просить допомогти знайти певну інформацію, однак їй дають посилання на відеокліп Ріка Естлі "Never Gonna Give You Up". Гугл перекладач дає варіант "рендеринг", що точно не є вірно. В російській мові я знайшов варіант ["рикроллинг"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3). Отож, як можна перекласти це слово українською і як бути із виразом: "You've got Rickrolled" - "Вас відрікролилли"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## За чинним правописом — 2015

> #### [§ 87. G, H](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par87)
>
> **G** і **h** звичайно передаються літерою **г**: *авангард, агітація, агресор, гвардія, генетика, гімнастика, гоніометр, грандіозний, графік, грог, ембарго, лінгвістика, міграція; гандбол, гегемонія, гектар, гербарій, герцог, гінді (мова), гіпотеза, горизонт, госпіталь, гугенот, гумус; Гаага, Гавана, Гавр, Гарвард, Гаронна, Гвінея, Гельсінгфорс, Гельсінкі, Гіндустан, Гренландія, Греція, Йоганнесбург, Люксембург; Ганнібал, Гейне, Гете, Гізо, Гомер, Горацій, Горн, Гюго, Магомет.*
>
> ---
>
> #### [§ 89. Неподвоєні й подвоєні приголосні](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par89)
>
> 1. У загальних назвах іншомовного походження приголосні звичайно не подвоюються: *акумуляція, бароко, беладона, белетристика, бравісимо, ват* (хоч *Ватт*), *грип, група, групето, гун (гуни), ідилічний, інтелектуальний, інтермецо, колектив, комісія, комуна, лібрето, піанісимо, піцикато, стакато, сума, фін (фіни), фортисимо, шасі, шофер* та ін.
>
> ---
>
> *Відоміше як [виняток 9](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2'%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8)*
>
> #### [§ 90. J](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par90p5v)
>
> 5. в) **И** пишеться:
>
>    1) у загальних назвах після приголосних **д, т, з, с, ц, ж (дж), ч, ш, р** перед наступним приголосним: *дизель, динамо, диплом, директор, методика; інститут, математика, стимул, текстиль, тип; зиґзаґ, позиція, фізичний; марксизм, силует, система; цистерна, цифра; жирандоль, режим, джигіт, джинси; речитатив, чичероне; ширма, шифр; бригада, риф, фабрика;*

Якщо перебуквувати, то маємо **рикролінг**.

## Все?

Журба в тому, що тут зібралися 2 найсуперечливих правила: совітський *г—ґ* і наче-польський *виняток 9*, котрий збережений совітами — не дивно, є деякі наближення до московської.

### Правило *ґ—г* й звук *ŋ*

Теперішнє правило справедливо називають совітським, саме тодї прибрали геть букву *ґ* і поєднали з *г*. Очевидно, при прямого перебуквування — саме так і зазвичай всі найперше роблять, коли нема точно відповідного звуку — належно писати як *-ґ*, оскільки анґлійську *g* зазвичай сприймають як звук */g/*, якому відповідають *ґ* і московська *г*. Цебто матимемо **р‑кролінґ**. Хто переймається пошуком Google: коли не вживати спеціяльні сімволи, пошук не [дуже] розрізняє *г* та *ґ*.

Инший підхід — відшукувати найближчі звуки. Букви *ng* позначають звуку *[/ŋ/](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velar_nasal)*, котрого [не маємо](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96). Найближчі відповідники: *[/ɲ/](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatal_nasal)* чи */nʲ/* — *нн(ь)* чи *нь*. Таким чином матимемо **‑лінн**, **‑лінь** чи навіть можливе **-лін**. Особисто я за перший спосіб, оскільки дуже подібне до нашого закінчення *‑ння*, котре має схожу роль.

### [Виняток 9](/a/3784/585)

Буде **рікролін-**.

## А переклад?

Є думка, шчо *меми* чи подібне **не треба перекладати**.

А так, тут *Rick* є іменем, тому не перекласти, залишок — *roll[ing]*, котрого можна перекласти на основі дїєслова *крутити* від *круть* до *крутїння*.

Також існує думка (тут пана [Sasha](/users/4/sasha)) бра́ти за основу «проходити» чи «прокочувати» (наче [котком](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)), тобто [roller](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_roller) — зокрема враховуючи, що rickrolling передував [duckrolling](//knowyourmeme.com/memes/duckroll)). Отже, можливе також 
 р‑кувати.

Comment: Мені здається, «rolling» тут радше не «крутити», а «проходити»/«прокочувати» (наче [котком](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Коток_(машина)), тобто [roller](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_roller) — зокрема враховуючи, що rickrolling'у передував [duckrolling](//knowyourmeme.com/memes/duckroll)). Отже, можливо, якщо вже перекладати, то якось «від'Rick'ували»/«про'Rick'ували», «відр{і/и}чили»/«прор{і/и}чили» або «{від/про}[(рік)ес(т)л](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Рік_Естлі)или».

Answer (score 2):

*all the credits go to @Sasha and his [comment](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3834/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-rickrolling#comment6617_3834)*

Слово Rickrolling містить у собі ім'я співака, отже перекладати його було б дивно, тоді просто застосуємо [правила запозичення загальних назв](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm) і [правило дев'ятки](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8):

1. Правило дев'ятки:

> У чинному правописі вимагає писати в запозичених загальних назвах
> після 9 приголосних, д, т, з, с, ц, ж, ш, ч, р, перед наступною
> літерою, що позначає приголосний звук (крім «й») літеру «и» на місці
> «і»: сигнал, динамо, режим, дизель, зиґзаґ, принтер тощо — а не
> сігнал, дінамо, режім, дізель, зіґзаґ, прінтер, як у першоджерелі.

2. Правила запозичення загальних назв:

> У загальних назвах іншомовного походження приголосні звичайно не подвоюються
>
> При збігу однакових приголосних префікса й кореня подвоєний приголосний маємо лише тоді, коли в мові вживається паралельне непрефіксальне слово

Паралельного непрефіксального слова немає, тож писатимемо так:

### Відрикролити

Отже, "**вас відрикролили**".

Іменник писатимемо за [оцим правилом](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F):

### Рикролінґ

[Правопис](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm) у цьому плані суттєво застарів і не встигає за динамікою книжної спільноти (яка активно ([Гемінґвей](https://starylev.com.ua/news/ernest-gemingvey-ukrayinske-perezavantazhennya), [Гокінґ](https://starylev.com.ua/dzhordzh-i-nezlamnyy-kod), [Воннеґут+Ґалапаґос](http://www.books-xxi.com.ua/products/galapagos), [Ваґнер](http://www.books-xxi.com.ua/products/blyuz-kentavriv), [Ґюнтер Ґрасс](https://starylev.com.ua/moye-storichchya), [Бротіґан](http://komubook.com.ua/projects/pidtrymaty-vydannya-lovlya-foreli-v-amerytsi), [Євґєній](http://komubook.com.ua/projects/my-druhe-vydannya), [Біґ-Сур](http://komubook.com.ua/projects/pidtrymaty-vydannya-general-konfederatsii-z-big-sur) повертає правильну транскрипцію замість фрикативізації всього навколо).