# Чи стане слово “серфінг” (surfing) усталеним та самостійним?

Tags: переклад, вживання-слів, from-english

Цікаво дізнатися, чи отримало/отримує слово **серфінг** (в Інтернеті, тобто перегляд сторінок веб сайтів, сторінок соціальних мереж), поширення в українському сучасному суспільстві?

Українські словники поки що "мовчать", а от в англійських слово з'явилось:

[Cambridge Advanced Learner’s Dictionary & Thesaurus](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/surfing)

> surfing *noun* [ U ] (INTERNET) 
>   ​the activity of spending time visiting different websites on the internet: 
>   internet surfing
>   Thesaurus: synonyms and related words

І чи правильне його написання кирилицею саме *"серфінг"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спочатку трошки означень. Як показано у запитанні:

[Питомі та усталені слова. Потребую допомоги з методом визначення](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/420/)

**усталеним** слово стає тоді, коли воно опиняється у словниках. У комбінації з твердженням:

> *Українські словники поки що "мовчать"*

це є відповіддю на запитання, чи це слово вже є **усталеним** (ще ні), і за яких обставин можна буде вважати деяке слово — **усталеним** (коли зʼявиться у словниках).
На запитання, *коли* це станеться, відповіді не існує, бо ми не можемо прогнозувати майбутнє.

---

Стосовно правопису, напевне, мається на увазі правопис слів, запозичених з англійської, і які закінчуються на `-ing`. Тобто, дві проблеми:

- `-инг` чи `-інг` (голосна)
- `-інг` чи `-інґ` (кінцева приголосна)

Стосовно голосної, користуємося [**правилом девʼятки**](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/334/) (девʼять приголосних, після яких пишеться `-и-`). Отже, у цьому слові пишемо `-і-`.

Стосовно кінцевої приголосної, правопис суфіксу `-ing` досліджено, [наприклад, тут](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/3859/), автор радить писати `-г`, а не `-ґ`.

Отже, загалом маємо правопис **серфінг**.

Comment: Мені здається що в такій формі - сЕрфінг - це опосередковане запозичення через російську мову. Surfing вимовляється як sərfiNG, тож мабуть українською мало б бути сьорфінг. В російській це запозичення, як пише їхня Вікі https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%91%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3 мало б писатися як Сёрфинг але спростилося до Серфинг

Comment: @hutorny зазначу, що *surfing* вимовляється ріжними способами (наприклад американська *r* трохи инша), але переважно через [[ɜ\]](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_central_unrounded_vowel), ось до прикладу джерело [[sɜː.fɪŋ\]](//dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/surfing), хоча не заперечує, що инколи і як [[ə\]](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid_central_vowel#Mid_central_unrounded_vowel). Також зазначу, що [клясичний](//r2u.org.ua/node/244) твердить так: _§ 66. […] англійське **u** в закритому складі передаємо через **е**: Гарфлер, Сент-Бев, Тепфер, Ґете, Шлецер, Бернс, Де́фферін і т. ін._

Comment: Пане *bytebuster*, _автор_ не радить, а лиш наголошує як писати за _чинним — 2012(5) — правописом_. І про всяк також про ймовірні написання поза чинним правописом через лоґістічні питання з _винятком 9_ і передачі _g‑h_: про перебуквування (котре сходиться також і з клясичним), перезвукування і втїлення „твердої“ **і** — так, в цїлому дослїдження і де перші два тут цїлком підійдуть, так.